# How to set selectedindex of select2 (version 3.5) dropdown in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, selectedindex

Simple question, yet no answers yet. 
Is it possible to set the selectedIndex of the Select2 dropdown via an ordinal number? I'm using Select2 version 3.5.2 and find it quite easy to have a selected item using a value as in:

```
$(elem).select2('val','my value',false);
```

however, trying to make a selection via an ordinal, completely escapes me. Some examples of what works with a normal dropdown, but not with Select2:

```
$(elem + " option")[1].selected = true; //no worky
$(elem + " option:eq(1)").attr("selected", "selected"); //no worky
$(elem).prop({ selectedIndex: 1 });//no worky
```

The reason I need this is to have a default selection that's not the first one, as the Select2 uses the first option (Index: 0) to fill in the hints, so I want to default to Index: 1 (and they can have many different values, so I can't just set the selected option via a value - it must be an ordinal.

UPDATE:
The problem may be here (the value is empty for all the ALL selections as well as the required empty option) - it may be confused.

```
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="">All Sizes</option>
<option value="6ad0a51e-e58c-4431-914d-b3f1a6b2c08e">18in X 18in</option>
<option value="a00b492e-08fa-4824-ad86-9ffb8a510be2">9.75in X 39in</option>
<option value="423b2a4e-2876-4969-84e3-3601e3fab524">19.7in X 19.7in</option>
<option value="9d4f4f13-47f6-422c-bbaf-f0911b5c156c">12in x 36in</option>
<option value="d417f0bc-d1fe-4d6b-bf41-aa081907254c">22in X 22in</option>
<option value="d1dc3ca6-fc3c-47f8-8b71-80219c8fd98b">24in X 24in</option>
<option value="c92c91a3-dfdb-4240-83e2-c08771748e47">18in x 36in</option>
<option value="4741d76f-628f-4ca0-a871-dfe2c4986e66">19.7in X 39.4in</option>
<option value="f70791ba-c56a-403b-b23e-fb2e8869ba07">36in X 36in</option>
<option value="7f70b445-a890-4838-a9f5-4c3100643fdd">39in X 39in</option>
```

I'll give the first option a value ("all sizes","all colors", "only in-stock items", "sale categories only", etc) and set them to the same value like "-" from the database as the first item (that way, I don't need to compare).
It would still be nice to set a selectedIndex (lot's of old code to be updated) - I'll post it in their requests for future revisions of Select2

UPDATE:
Here's what the function looks like

```
function setDD(elem, qs) {
    var q = QueryString(qs);
    if (!(typeof q === "undefined")) {
        if (q === '') {
            //$(elem + " option")[1].selected = true; //no worky
            //$(elem + " option:eq(1)").attr("selected", "selected"); //no worky
            //$(elem).prop({ selectedIndex: 1 });//no worky
            //$(elem).find("option:eq(1)").prop("selected", "selected"); //no worky
            //$(elem + " option:eq(1)").prop("selected", "selected");  //no worky
            //$(elem).prop('selectedIndex', 1).change(); //no worky
        } else {
            $(elem).select2('val', q, false);
        };
    }; //else leave the dropdown at its default to show the hint (until user actually makes a selection)
};
```

Comment: `$(elem + " option:eq(1)").prop("selected", "selected");` try using prop instead of attr or like this `$(elem).find("option:eq(1)").prop("selected", "selected");`

Comment: unfortunately, this is ignored as well.  Works great on the plain old select dropdown, just not on Select2.  I noticed version 4.0 has no means of selecting an option by index, either (at least not in the documentation).

Comment: If you change the value of the original select element, you need to trigger its change event to get the Select2 control to update. Try `$(elem).prop('selectedIndex', 1).change();`.

Comment: no joy with this, either. I'll try the change with the other methods, see if it works.

Comment: You are not going to be able to get this to work if you have two options with the same value. That is, you will not be able to select the second one by index. If you change the underlying select element, the Select2 control doesn't know to update until you trigger the change event. But when the change event is triggered, the Select2 control updates itself by getting the value of the selected option, not the index of that option. So having two options with the same value is going to cause Select2 to select the first one that matches.

Comment: What I figured. 
So the answer is that Select2 does not allow selecting by index at all.

Comment: Well, it definitely does not provide a method to select by index, but there clearly is a way to select by index provided the options have unique values. To be fair though, there is no requirement on a select element that options have unique values.

Answer (score 7):

Although Select2 does not provide a method for selecting by index, you can set the value of the underlying `<select>` element by index. Of course, whenever you change the value of the underlying `<select>` element, you need to trigger its `change` event in order for the Select2 control to know that it needs to update itself to match.

So you can do:

```
$(elem).prop('selectedIndex', 1).change();
```

---

But this is not going to work if the selected index refers to an option that does not have a unique value. When the Select2 control updates itself, it looks at the value of the underlying `<select>` element, not its selected index.

Of course, you can't select a non-unique option by value, but you could trying using the Select2 "data" method, like this:

```
var $option = $(elem).children().eq(1);
$(elem).select2('data', { id: $option.val(), text: $option.text() });
```

In the general case, one issue I see with this is that when the Select2 is opened (i.e., the drop-down is shown), the highlighted option is the first one in the list with the non-unique value. If the user then presses the Tab key, that option will become the selected option.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/09dkvjcp/)

But for your limited case, where the only non-unique options are two options with empty values, and the first of which has no text (i.e., an empty body), then the code above appears to work.

I assume that you are specifying the "placeholder" option with the "allowClear" option set to `true`. Otherwise the user can never switch back to the empty option. (So why have it.)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fL5cgj0d/2/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('select').val('US'); // Change the value or make some change to the internal state
$('select').trigger('change.select2'); // Notify only Select2 of changes
```

try this one.

Comment: No way to set the selectedIndex?   I suppose I could check the value (there's dozens of dropdowns each with different default values - I was trying to avoid this to make it act like before using Select2 where you could select the option by its index (instead of value). Maybe this is just not possible with this control (a gross oversight IMHO)

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery Select2 control does not allow selecting of an option by it's ordinal index.
The ONLY solution is to set a selected option by it's value (at least in version 3.5).
I hate this answer!